# sqlite optimization on inner join with tables values around 18K

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables tool , tool_attribute.
tool has 12 columns and tool_attribute has 5.

**Information i needed from the tables :**

1. tool - refid, serial, type, id
2. tool_attribute - key, value, id (There will be multiple entries for this)

Right now i have around 18264 in tool and 255696 in tool_attribute

**Current Query :**

```
select
    tool.refid,
    tool.serial,
    tool_attribute.value,
tool.type
from tool
inner join tool_attribute
    on tool.id = tool_attribute.id
where
    (tool_attribute.val LIKE '%t00%' or
     tool.serial LIKE '%t00%')
group by tool.refid
order by tool.serial asc;
```

This take around 750ms which is quite fast but i want to make it much faster. I run this code on low memory windows 6.0 device so it takes too much time.
Is there any way i could make it faster ?

Comment: What is this `t00`? If it is an important piece of information, it might be worthwhile to put it into its own column.

Comment: No its just an sample text.  It may vary

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding indices to the columns involved in the join:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tool ON tool (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_tool_attr ON tool_attribute (id);
```

The `LIKE` conditions in your `WHERE` clause would preclude any chance of using an index on the columns involved, I think.  The reason for this is a `LIKE` expression of the form `%something` eliminates the chance to search through a B-tree, which uses the suffix from left to right to find something.  If you could rephrase your `WHERE` logic using something similar to `LIKE 'something%'` then an index could be used there as well.

Comment: The problem is i cannot use index . The id on tool_attribute will have duplicate values.

Comment: @user3383301 You can still use an index on a column with duplicate values.  So long as you don't have really low cardinality, you should be fine.